# Warning using ICC and printf with thousands grouping format (apostrophe)

Tags: c, locale, printf, number-formatting, icc

I need to display some numbers with thousands grouping (in this case, using period as separator). So, I'm using the printf flag `'` to achieve such thing.

With `gcc` everything goes well, but if I use `icc`, then I get this warning:

> warning #269: invalid format string conversion

despite the fact that the number is indeed printed with the desired format.

For example, if we compile this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "da_DK");
    int i = 12345678;
    unsigned long int j = 987654321;

    printf("%d \t %'d \n%lu \t %'lu \n", i, i, j, j);
}
```

then we get this warning:

```
% icc -o simple simple.c 

simple.c(10): warning #269: invalid format string conversion
  printf("%d \t %'d \n%lu \t %'lu \n", i, i, j, j);
                                          ^
```

despite the fact that everything works as expected:

```
% ./simple 
12345678         12.345.678 
987654321        987.654.321
```

So my questions are:

1. How can this warning be suppressed?
2. Is it safe to use `'` as flag with printf and friends, with the `icc` compiler?

---

**UPDATE**:

I've just realized that an strange trick to suppress the `269` warning is defining a variable with the format, and pass that variable to `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "da_DK");
    int i = 12345678;
    unsigned long int j = 987654321;
    const char *strFormat = "%d \t %'d \n%lu \t %'lu \n";

    printf(strFormat, i, i, j, j);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Because using apostrophe with `printf` is an XSI Extension (as stated by @Dave), in order to make the code more portable may be more useful to follow the recommendation from the [C-FAQ, question 12.11](http://c-faq.com/stdio/commaprint.html) and use their implementation of `commaprint`.

Comment: Does `-wd269` on the command line disable the warning?

Comment: @PaulR: `gcc` doesn't complain, even compiling with `-Wall`.

Comment: @HostileFork: Yes, with that option the warning gets disabled, but it will also disable any other error or problem regarding the code 269.

Comment: Well just happened to see a mailing list saying this didn't work: `#pragma warning ( push )`, `#pragma warning ( disable: 269 )`, [offending code], `#pragma warning( pop )`...but that the command line switch did.  :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your second question, The compiler doesn't actually control the processing of your format string; that's your C library's job. `icc` doesn't recognize the format string because it is nonstandard, but as long as you understand that your code will only be valid on platforms whose c libraries support the `'` flag, you'll be ok.

As the [opengroup page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) shows, `'` is an XSI extension, so your code will work on any XSI-conformant platform.

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void punt(int n){
    char s[28];
    int i = 27;
    if(n<0){n=-n; putchar('-');} 
    do{
        s[i--] = n%10 + '0';
        if(!(i%4) && n>9)s[i--]=' ';
        n /= 10;
    }while(n);
    puts(&s[++i]);
}


int main(){

    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    punt(a);

}
```

or so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[50];
    int len = 0;   
    scanf("%48[^\n]%n", str, &len);

    int start = len % 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {        
        if(i == start && i != 0) {
            printf(" ");
        } else if((i - start) % 3 == 0 && i != 0) {
            printf(" ");
        }    
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }   

   return 0;
}
```